# Is this the right way to use recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

> Given strings `s` and `t` compute recursively, if `t` is contained in `s` return `true`.
>
> Example: `bool find("Names Richard", "Richard") == true`;

I have written the code below, but I'm not sure if its the right way to use recursion in C++; I just learned recursion today in class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool find(string s, string t)
{
    if (s.empty() || t.empty())
        return false;
    int find = static_cast<int>(s.find(t));
    if (find > 0)
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool b = find("Mississippi", "sip");
    string s;
    if (b == 1) s = "true";
    else 
        s = "false";
    cout << s;
}
```

If anyone find an error in my code, please tell me so I can fix it or where I can learn/read more about this topic. I need to get ready for a test on recursion on this Wednesday.

Comment: Your code [always returns true](http://ideone.com/2MAQk).

Comment: @minitech No.. I think the OP should speak in the first place, it is a homework...

Comment: @Beginner: Sorry, comment already edited. :P

Comment: Your function isn't recursive anymore

Comment: What is the purpose of your call to `s.substr (0, 2)`?

Comment: @Richard, I recommend creating a new post. You've caused much confusion by editing your post.

Answer (score 4):

### The question has changed since I wrote my answer.

My comments are on the code that looked like this (and *could* recurse)...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool find(string s, string t)
{
    if (s.empty() || t.empty())
        return false;
    string start = s.substr(0, 2);
    if (start == t && find(s.substr(3), t));
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool b = find("Mississippi", "sip");
    string s;
    if (b == 1) s = "true";
    else 
        s = "false";
    cout << s;
}
```

---

Watch out for this:

```
if (start == t && find(s.substr(3), t));
    return true;
```

This does not do what you think it does.

The `;` at the end of the `if`-statement leaves an empty body. Your `find()` function will return `true` regardless of the outcome of that test.

I recommend you turn up the warning levels on your compiler to catch this kind of issue before you have to debug it.

As an aside, I find using braces around every code-block, even one-line blocks, helps me avoid this kind of mistake.

There are other errors in your code, too. Removing the magic numbers `2` and `3` from `find()`  will encourage you to think about what they represent and point you on the right path.

How would you expect `start == t && find(s.substr(3), t)` to work? If you can express an algorithm in plain English (or your native tongue), you have a much higher chance of being able to express it in C++.

Additionally, I recommend adding test cases that should return `false` (such as `find("satsuma", "onion")`) to ensure that your code works as well as calls that should return `true`.

The last piece of advice is stylistic, laying your code out like this will make the boolean expression that you are testing more obvious without resorting to a temporary and comparing to `1`:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    if (find("Mississippi", "sip"))
    {
        s = "true";
    }
    else
    {
        s = "false";
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Good luck with your class!

Comment: opps, my bad... i didnt notice that. Thanks!

Comment: Nice catch - I still do this every now and then when porting code around.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive function needs 2 things:

1. Definite conditions of failure and success (may be more than 1)
2. a call of itself to process a simpler version of the problem (getting closer to the answer).

Here's a quick analysis:

```
bool find(string s, string t)
{
    if (s.empty() || t.empty())  //definite condition of failure. Good
        return false;
    string start = s.substr(0, 2);
    if (start == t && find(s.substr(3), t)); //mixed up definition of success and recursive call
        return true;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
bool find(string s, string t)
{
    if (s.empty() || t.empty())  //definite condition of failure. Done!
        return false;
    string start = s.substr(0, 2); 
    if (start == t)  //definite condition of success. Done!
        return true;
    else            
        return find(s.substr(3), t) //simply the problem and return whatever it finds
}
```

Comment: @Beginner the top answer isn't the solution to the problem

Comment: @kisplit It shouldn't be, since this is a homework. Or you have a different opinion on that? However I meant a semicolon after *if (start == t)*

Comment: @Beginner I do have a different opinion actually. When someone makes a simple, if (x = y) mistake but wanted to know about z then why not spend the majority of time explaining z instead of dwelling on the mistake he already understands?

Comment: @kisplit Exactly this hint was given in the top answer. You thought votes were for correct solution? And debugging adventures only help young programmers...

Comment: @Beginner I'm sorry, why was this answer downvoted? Should I not have given an exact answer and instead just provided hints as this is homework? I don't doubt that it deserves the downvotes and I'll gladly delete it if it is nonconstructive, but I'd like to know what mistake I made so I don't do it again first. :D

Comment: Firstly yes, you should have provided only hint, anyway this is my personal policy. You can do what you want. Secondly, yes, your code has a mistake. Its description is in my third comment.

Comment: @Beginner You can keep believing that telling someone their shoes are untied and walking away is somehow tremendously more valuable than teaching them how to make their own shoelaces. <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right lines - so long as the function calls itself you can say that it's recursive - but even the most simple testing should tell you that your code doesn't work correctly.  Change `"sip"` to `"sipx"`, for example, and it still outputs `true`.  Have you compiled and run this program?  Have you tested it with various different inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using recursion. Using `std::string::find` in your function feels like cheating (this will most likely not earn points).

The only reasonable interpretation of the task is: Check if `t` is an infix of `s` without using loops or string functions.

Let's look at the trivial case: Epsilon (the empty word) is an infix of ever word, so if `t.empty()` holds, you must return `true`.
Otherwise you have two choices to make:

1. `t` might be a prefix of `s` which is simple to check using recursion; simply check if the first character of `t` equals the first character of `s` and call `isPrefix` with the remainder of the strings. If this returns true, you return true.
2. Otherwise you pop the first character of `s` (and not of `t`) and proceed recursively (calling `find` this time).

If you follow this recipe (which btw. is easier to implement with `char const*` than with `std::string` if you ask me) you get a recursive function that only uses conditionals and no library support.

*Note: this is **not** at all the most efficient implementation, but you didn't ask for efficiency but for a recursive function.*

Comment: bool find(string s, string t)
{
    if (s.empty()) return false;
    if (t.empty()) return true;
    if (s[0] == t[0])
    {
        if (s.substr(0, t.length()) == t)
            return true;
    }
    return find((s.substr(1)), t);
} is this right?

Comment: @RichardNguyen: If you ask me, using `std::string::substr` still feels like cheating for a homework task. However returning `true` for `t.empty()` must take precedence to returning `false` for `s.empty()` because the empty string contains itself. Otherwise your solution appears correct.